# How to remove a Markdown Separator Line in README with HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, readme

just have a question about the separator lines on README's on GitHub. I have my readme here if anyone wants to check it out: https://github.com/yashabnarang/Bonk-Bot/blob/master/README.md

I'm trying to remove the separator line below "Bonk Bot" and above LinkedIn Links. I tried to do the 2 spaces trick I saw on another Stack Overflow post but it did not work. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Here's the snippet of the markdown as well where its happening:

```
<h1 align="center" style="display: block; font-size: 2.5em; font-weight: bold; margin-block-start: 1em; margin-block-end: 1em;">  
  <img align="center" src="https://image_link" style="width:100%;height:100%"/>  
  <br><br><strong>Bonk Bot</strong>  
</h1>  
*******frustrating separator line here*******
<p  align="center">  
    <a  href="https://link">  
        <img src="https://image_link" />  
    </a>  
</p>
```

Comment: This is HTML, not Markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `p` inside of your `h1` just below the `<strong>Bonk Bot</strong>`
[image]

Comment: Bonk! This is perfect. This is exactly what I was hoping to do, and makes sense. Thank you